# Getting payload not working on product detail page (React, Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, typeerror, payload

I spent 2 days on this, but can't figure out why.
I'm building an e-commerce website using React, and payload is not loading and only 'loading' status is stuck to be true, then not getting any data from backend. I've tried everything I could, and found out that only 'ProductInfo' page is trying to getting data from 'localhost:3000/api/products' (the backend port is 5000 and 'Home' page is getting data from 5000 correctly)

Can somebody figure out where it is wrong?

---

Actions :

```
export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.PRODUCTS_LIST_REQUEST
    });

    try {
        const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/products');
        dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.PRODUCTS_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch(error) {
        dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.PRODUCTS_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message});
    }
};

export const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId });
    try {
      const { data } = Axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`);
      await dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ 
        type: ActionTypes.PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, 
        payload: 
        error.response && error.response.data.message 
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message
      });
    }
  };
```

---

reducers:

```
export const productListReducer = (state={ loading: true, products: []}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PRODUCTS_LIST_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true };
        case PRODUCTS_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, products: action.payload };
        case PRODUCTS_LIST_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const productDetailsReducer = (state={ loading: true }, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true };
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, product: action.payload};
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

---

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
        <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductInfo} exact />
        <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactStars from 'react-rating-stars-component';
import Loading from '../LoadingComponent';
import MessageBox from '../MessageBoxComponent';
import { SELLERS } from '../../shared/sellers';
import './ProductInfo.css';
import { detailsProduct} from '../../redux/actionCreators';


function ProductInfo(props) {
  
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productId = props.match.params.id;
    const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;
    
    console.log(productDetails);
    useEffect((productId) => {
        dispatch(detailsProduct(productId));
    }, [dispatch, productId]);



    const seller = SELLERS.find((seller) => seller._id === product.sellerId);
    
    const [ showImage, setShowImage ] = useState(product.imageUrl[0]);

    const renderImages = product.imageUrl.map(image => (
        <div className="info__smallImgBox" onClick={() => setShowImage(image)}>
            <img 
                src={image} 
                className="info__smallImg" 
                alt={product.name+' image'}
            />
        </div>
    ));


    return (
        
        <div className="info__container">
            <Link to="/"><div className="info__goBack"><span><i className="fa fa-angle-left" /> BACK TO MAIN</span></div></Link>
            {loading?  <Loading />
            : error? <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
            :(<div className="info__content">
                <div className="info__main">
                    <div className="info__imageBox">
                        <img src={showImage} className="info__image" alt={product.name}/>
                        <div className="info__imageCarousel">
                            {renderImages}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="info__description">
                        <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                        <div className="info__ratings row">
                            <ReactStars  
                                count={5}
                                value={product.rating}
                                size={15}
                                activeColor="yellow"
                                edit={false}
                            />
                            <span> {product.numReviews + (product.numReviews>0? " reviews" : " review")}</span>
                        </div>
                        <h3>${product.price}</h3>
                        <h4><span className="head">Materials </span>  {product.material}</h4>
                        <h4><span className="head">Description </span> {product.description}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="info__action">
                    <div className="info__seller row">
                        <h3>Seller</h3>
                        <h3>{seller.name}</h3>
                    </div>
                
                    <div className="info__ratings row" style={{paddingLeft:0}}>
                        <ReactStars 
                            count={5}
                            value={product.rating}
                            size={15}
                            activeColor="yellow"
                            edit={false}
                        />
                        <h3> {product.numReviews + (product.numReviews>0? " reviews" : " review")}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <h3>Price</h3>
                        <h3>${product.price}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row"> 
                        <h3>Status</h3>
                        <h3>{product.countInStock > 5 ? (<span className="">In Stock</span>) : product.countInStock > 0? (<span className="red">Only {product.countInStock} In Stock</span>): (<span className="red">Unavailable</span>)}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row" style={{margin: '2rem 0'}}>
                        <label for="qty">Qty</label>
                        <select name="qty" style={{color: 'black', fontSize:"1.8rem", height: '2.9rem', padding: '3px 10px'}} >
                            <option >select</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row center">
                        <button className="">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>)}
        </div>
    )
}


export default ProductInfo;
```

==========

THE ERROR MESSAGE : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sellerId' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a couple of issues here. But here is what I have noticed.

1. When you fetch data from back-end, you have to specify the full url for Axios. Otherwise, it will try to fetch it from the current url. So this code will need to be changed to contain the full back-end url:

From this:

```
const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/products');
```

To something like this:

```
const { data } = await Axios.get('https://my-backend.com/api/products');
```

And the same thing for the other calls to the back-end.

2. In your `ProductInfo` component, you are trying to get id from the product object. But this variable does not exist. I think you meant either `productDetails` or use directly `productId`

`const seller = SELLERS.find((seller) => seller._id === product.sellerId);`

Comment: Thank you so so much for your reply. I'm desperate. I have tried literally everything I could, and I also changed the url for axiios by adding my personal ip or localhost, and it gave network error. (the 'seller' line, I changed it not to get additional error). The strangest thing is, why I can get 'product lists' without problem, while I get an empty payload for only the specific item? I really don't understand this.